# Vue component with API call in Laravel + Inertia

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I can't undestand how to create a new Vue component inside my app created with Laravel and Inertia.

The problem is that I can't make a call from the component to an API (in the `routes/api.php` file) that is protected by an auth middleware (like `auth:api`).

There is a practical example:

I manage a list of customers in my app. Then I manage invoices. So, in the invoice creation form I must select one of the customers in my database. I want to make a componente (like `<SelectCustomer v-model="form.customer" />` maybe) where inside itself I can make an API call that return the list of all customers to populate my select.

Obviously, that API is reserved only for the logged user, so has a middleware guard.

It's possible to make an `axios` call - maybe - in the component's methods? but with what informations? maybe I must obtain a bearer token?

Comment: Yes, it would make sense for the client to make the API request, and it's possible to make Axios calls from component methods. The API request should include an auth header (OAuth or JWT), which the server would use to verify the user is permitted to access the endpoint.

Comment: Where would one access the auth header?